# css - RShiny widgets: How to color the radioButtons() and checkboxGroupInput()?

Tags: css, r, checkbox, shiny, radio-button

I'm using many different `checkboxGroupInput()` and `radioButtons()` in my RShiny app, one code snippet looks like this:

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "maDays", label = "Select Trading Days", 
                                      choices = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                                                  "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"),
                                      selected = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                                                   "Friday"), 
                                      inline = TRUE),
radioButtons(inputId = "maTimeGran", label = "Select Time Granularity", 
                                choices = c("Hourly" = "hour", "Daily" = "day", 
                                            "Weekly" = "week"),
                                selected = "day")
```

and gives:

[image]
[image]

Now my question is: How can I change the **coloring** of all my selected radioButtons (button, not text) and checkmarks (not text) with a `css`-tag? My preferred color would be `#007d3c`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adapt the approach from https://dev.to/kallmanation/styling-a-radio-button-with-only-css-4llc to get this to work.  (The checkboxes have a solid fill color instead of checkmarks when selected.)

Here's the code:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
                    label > input[type='radio'] {
                        opacity: 0;
                        position: absolute;
                    }
                    label > input[type='radio'] + *::before {
                        content: '';
                        margin: 4px 0 0;
                        width: 13px;
                        height: 13px;
                        position: absolute;
                        margin-left: -20px;
                        border-radius: 50%;
                        border-style: solid;
                        border-width: 0.1rem;
                        border-color: #007d3c;
                    }
                    label > input[type='radio']:checked + *::before {
                        background: radial-gradient(white 0%, white 30%, #007d3c 30%, #007d3c);
                                border-color: #007d3c;
                    }
                    label > input[type='checkbox'] {
                        opacity: 0;
                        position: absolute;
                    }
                    label > input[type='checkbox'] + *::before {
                      content: '';
                      position: absolute;
                      margin: 4px 0 0;
                      margin-left: -20px;
                      align: center;
                      width: 13px;
                      height: 13px;
                      margin-right: 1rem;
                      border-radius: 0%;
                      border-style: solid;
                      border-width: 0.1rem;
                      border-color: #007d3c;
                    }
                    label > input[type='checkbox']:checked + *::before {
                      content: '';
                      width: 13px;
                      height: 13px;
                      background-color: #007d3c;
                    }
                  "))
    ),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "maDays", label = "Select Trading Days", 
                       choices = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                                   "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"),
                       selected = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                                    "Friday"), 
                       inline = TRUE),
    radioButtons(inputId = "maTimeGran", label = "Select Time Granularity", 
                 choices = c("Hourly" = "hour", "Daily" = "day", 
                             "Weekly" = "week"),
                 selected = "day")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    ## put server code here
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here's my original answer, which styles the labels for checked elements, in case this is useful to anyone else:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
                  input:checked + span {
                    color: #007d3c;
                  }
                  "))
    ),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "maDays", label = "Select Trading Days", 
                       choices = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                                   "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"),
                       selected = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                                    "Friday"), 
                       inline = TRUE),
    radioButtons(inputId = "maTimeGran", label = "Select Time Granularity", 
                 choices = c("Hourly" = "hour", "Daily" = "day", 
                             "Weekly" = "week"),
                 selected = "day")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  ## put server code here
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: When I use this, then the text (Monday, ... hourly, ...) is colored (what I don't want) and not the checkmarks and the buttons. Do you know, how a ```css``` for colored checkmarks and buttons could be?

Comment: That's a bit more complex, but this page might be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have already tried to do this (your link to the webside) with my checkboxes and radiobuttons, but it doesn't work for me or in my case.